# Is there a function in jquery.validate that will reset a single field like resetForm does for a form?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to call a jquery function to manually remove errors from a single field and reset the error markup.  Is there a function that does this that would be similar to the resetForm function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**this**](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/resetForm) resets the entire form

```
var validator = $("#myform").validate();
validator.resetForm();
```

[**this**](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/removeAttrs#attributes) will reset only the `name` element

```
$("#skip").click(function() {
   var rules = $("#name").removeAttrs("min max"); // remove min and max
   $("#form").submit(); // submit, as there are no attributes, it will not have an error
   $("#name").attr(rules); // add it again so you can validate it
});
```

Comment: if the answer is not useful, tell us why please. Don't downvote without a reason...

Comment: The question asks to remove errors from a single field: the proposed solution doesn't do that. It validates the entire form, and doesn't remove the existing errors.

Comment: Well I didn't say I downvoted, but that's irrelevant anyway, if a solution is wrong it should be downvoted and there's no requirement for an alternative to be left.  As for your solution, I just tried it, and indeed it doesn't work, as I said before it's going to validate the entire form as soon as you click on the "skip" element, and there's no code there to clear any existing errors.  See http://jsfiddle.net/9rNv5/. If you have a working solution it may be worth expanding on your answer.

Comment: true if: **if a solution is wrong**, but it was not wrong by the time of the answer (2011) as that was the only way to accomplish it.

Comment: I believe you're wrong on a number of counts. Firstly, the question is still a valid question today, and the solution posted will not work using tools used today, hence the solution is invalid. Secondly, whilst you may be correct that this worked 3 years ago, I don't believe this to be the case.  The solution does not work using earliest version of jquery on jsfiddle (1.6.4), released in September 2011, and the version of jquery validate available at that time. Your solution does a $("form").submit(), which causes the entire form to be validated - I don't see how this could ever work.

Comment: Agree with David_001

Comment: @David_001 a bit more attention will tell you that `removeAttrs` were [removed in 2015](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=removeAttrs&type=) but you can see the source code for [1.11.1 still existed](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/blob/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js#L111) ... you can also see that the link I show points to an unexisting page as **removeAttrs** are no longer is supported. And **yes** even today you can submit a form [without actually causing it to submit](https://jsbin.com/wiximis/1/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 16):

You can do the following to validate a single field:

```
$('#your_field').valid();
```

Maybe it will help someone :-)

Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me.  But note that the valid() call must not be called before validate() setup is called or bad/strange things happen.

Comment: A perfect solution for the `selectize` auto-complete plugin. It happens to convert the `SELECT` elements into auto-complete (with optional multi-select) and makes the original SELECT control invisible (display: none;). This makes a) jQuery Validate ignore the element during validation, and b) doesn't remove the validation error displayed under the element (once you have instructed jQuery Validate to stop ignoring the hidden `SELECT`.) So I added solution above into the `change` event of the SELECT and voila! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Can't find anything built in to the validation library but this hack works:

```
$('#email').removeClass('error').next('label.error').remove();
```

Comment: year 2020  $('#email').removeClass('error').next('span.error').remove();

Answer (score 4):

This functionality is possible via `focusCleanup: true` option and triggering `focusin` event on desired element. But it is not always desirable to trigger this event. So apparently, you can use plugin’s  internal code which is running on `focusin` and invoke it externally like so:

```
/*get your element and containing validated form*/
var $that = $('#desired_elemenet');
var $form = $that.closest('form');

/*get validator object for the form*/
var validator = $form.validate();

/*use internal code of a plugin to clear the field*/
if (validator.settings.unhighlight) {
    validator.settings.unhighlight.call( validator, $that[0], validator.settings.errorClass, validator.settings.validClass );
}
validator.hideThese( validator.errorsFor( $that[0] ) );
```

Comment: This is the cleanest way to reset the element at this time :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var form = $('#form'); 
var validator = form.validate();

// Validate single field from that form.
var myfield = $('#myfield');
myfield.removeData('previousValue').removeAttr('aria-invalid');
validator.resetElements(myfield);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$("#selector").removeClass("error");
$("#selector-error").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

the function below will remove one or more error fields

```
/**
 * @name resetFields
 * @description clean one or more fields
 * @param {[string]} fieldsNameList
 * @param {jqueryValidatorInstance} validator
 *
 * @example
 *
 *  resetFields(['name'], validator)
 *
 */
function resetFields(fieldsNameList, validator){
    validator.invalid = {},
    validator.submitted = {},
    validator.prepareForm(),
    validator.hideErrors();
    validator.elements().filter((,el) => {
        return fieldsNameList.includes($(el).attr('name')) // if name include in current list of internal fields
    }).map((i, el) => {
        $(el).removeData("previousValue")
             .removeAttr("aria-invalid")
             .removeClass(validator.settings.errorClass)
             .removeClass(validator.settings.validClass)
    })
}

var validator = $form.validate();

resetFields(['name'], validator)
```