# Jquery validate plugin - reset specific sections of the form

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-validate

Using knockout, I need to reset certain templates, not the entire form. `resetForm()` resets everything. Anyone ran across this before?

I've looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998042/is-there-a-function-in-jquery-validate-that-will-reset-a-single-field-like-reset). I could probably do something like that. It just seems like it would get real messy fast with so many various fields and validation rules.

Comment: Hi Rick, please show a code example for some context of what you're trying to do, and please define "this". In other words, what exactly are you trying to do? What do you mean by "reset the template"?  Good luck! Here is the link to [edit] your post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working on a project with knockout and jquery validate at the moment. One thing I've settled upon is dividing the user input into subsections, essentially having multiple forms on the same page. Combine them all together and that's the total 'form' the user sees.

(Aside: I'm doing this because the API I'm submitting to has different expectations from what the form/UI/marketing dept. expects of the user experience. Each `<form>` is essentially a different API input section, but the marketing dept wanted to be able to order the user inputs arbitrarily, so I'm gathering them up by class:

```
<form class="api1">
     ... some inputs
</form>
<form class="api2">
    ... some different inputs
</form>
<form class="api1">
    ... some more inputs
</form>
```

I'm submitting these by Ajax (it's a single page app), so I'm not really losing anything from the standard form/action/submit/post model by doing this. But applying this to your situation, you could then essentially go:

```
$("#sectionId form.api1").each(function() {
    $(this).validate().reset();
});
```

I may have gotten that syntax wrong, I'm not using the reset function on jQuery validate. But now that I think about it, I probably could save some code if I did...

Feel free to post some code and I can better adapt my solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I currently have them all in one form. I think I might just break them down as you did. Thanks for the reply.